# turn a list into a set of arguments for a function

Tags: list, arguments, apply

I have a defun get-quotes with one mandatory and 2 optional arguments.  I would like to do something like this:

```
(let ((articles 
       '("/home/matt/art/mice.pdf" '("/home/matt/art/cats.pdf" "Smith, "Neural Pathways in Cat Brains" 3)))
  (dolist (thisarticle articles)
     (get-quotes (SOMEFUNCTION thisarticle)))
```

Where SOMEFUNCTION checks thisarticle, and if it's a string, passes it directly as an argument, or if it's a list, makes it available to get-quotes as a set of elements (rather than a list object).  My understanding of elisp is pretty vague, so I may be missing some fundamental point. Many thanks for the help!

The possible dupe in @Drew's post is quite helpful, but since the new answer from @abo-abo was a little easier for me to follow, I'm going to accept it rather than the slightly more technical answer in the earlier question.  Thanks to everyone though.

Comment: Well, `stringp` returns true `t` if an object is a string, `nil` otherwise.  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that did help.  And drew, now that i have ab0abo's answer, the answers in that link help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, the new function to learn is `apply`:

```cl
(defun get-quotes (x &rest y)
  (cons x y))
(let ((articles
       '("/home/matt/art/mice.pdf"
         ("/home/matt/art/cats.pdf"
          "Smith, \"Neural Pathways in Cat Brains\""
          3))))
  (dolist (thisarticle articles)
    (if (stringp thisarticle)
        (get-quotes thisarticle)
      (apply 'get-quotes thisarticle))))
```